# How to create custom categories that are visible only on the back end in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-taxonomy

For a blog with many companies/authors contributing to it, I would like to build custom categories for posts that are only visible on the back-end, and not able to be crawled by Google.

When an author creates a post, they can select

Company 1

Company 2

Company 3

from the list of categories, but these categories won't affect anything on the front-end, or be visible on the front-end. The client would like to be able to sort all posts by which company wrote them. Is there some functionality I can add to make these categories only visible on the back-end, or a plugin that would work for creating these?

Comment: Check the `register_taxonomy` arguments: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: Aha, I missed the "public" option the first time! Thanks!